# Where is pyformat documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for pyformat docs like where I can find all the tags tha are availabe in pyformat, because I don't find any place that gives me a full list of the parameters that.

I can use:

```
EX
'{my_string:0<15}'
'{my_string!u}'
```

etc...

Comment: did you really check the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in the associated PEP, [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-specifiers). There are a lot of specifiers, but the important ones is the overall format:

```
[[fill]align][sign][#][0][minimumwidth][.precision][type]
```

The alignment:

```
'<' - Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available
      space (This is the default.)
'>' - Forces the field to be right-aligned within the
      available space.
'=' - Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any)
      but before the digits.  This is used for printing fields
      in the form '+000000120'. This alignment option is only
      valid for numeric types.
'^' - Forces the field to be centered within the available
      space.
```

The sign:

```
'+'  - indicates that a sign should be used for both
       positive as well as negative numbers
'-'  - indicates that a sign should be used only for negative
       numbers (this is the default behavior)
' '  - indicates that a leading space should be used on
       positive numbers
```

The numerical display types:

```
'b' - Binary. Outputs the number in base 2.
'c' - Character. Converts the integer to the corresponding
      Unicode character before printing.
'd' - Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.
'o' - Octal format. Outputs the number in base 8.
'x' - Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using lower-
      case letters for the digits above 9.
'X' - Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using upper-
      case letters for the digits above 9.
'n' - Number. This is the same as 'd', except that it uses the
      current locale setting to insert the appropriate
      number separator characters.
'' (None) - the same as 'd'
```

And the floating point display types:

```
'e' - Exponent notation. Prints the number in scientific
      notation using the letter 'e' to indicate the exponent.
'E' - Exponent notation. Same as 'e' except it converts the
      number to uppercase.
'f' - Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point
      number.
'F' - Fixed point. Same as 'f' except it converts the number
      to uppercase.
'g' - General format. This prints the number as a fixed-point
      number, unless the number is too large, in which case
      it switches to 'e' exponent notation.
'G' - General format. Same as 'g' except switches to 'E'
      if the number gets to large.
'n' - Number. This is the same as 'g', except that it uses the
      current locale setting to insert the appropriate
      number separator characters.
'%' - Percentage. Multiplies the number by 100 and displays
      in fixed ('f') format, followed by a percent sign.
'' (None) - similar to 'g', except that it prints at least one
      digit after the decimal point.
```

Note that, while this may be comprehensive for builtin types like `int` and `float`, this **isn't** a comprehensive list for every type since they can make a custom `__format__` method that interprets format specifiers, which means types can add arbitrary format specifiers.